# How to setup daytime and nighttime trigger in Azure Synapse Analytics for pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I created one pipeline on Azure Synapse Analytics runing under trigger every 15 minutes right now.

Question:

I still want to run every 15 minutes on daytime for example 3am to 9pm.
I want to run onetime only at night after 9pm and before 3am for example 1am.

How do I create trigger for above request in Azure Synapse Analytics?
Can I write some code to do the trigger function in Microsoft Azure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup 2 triggers:

1. Scheduling trigger: set up for every 1 day. In hours, type in the hours you want the trigger to run on. In minutes, Type in 0,15,30,45 to run every 15 minutes.

[image: trigger1]

2. Scheduling trigger for the specific hour you want (1 am)